# Matlab matrix declaration in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have some old Matlab code I'm trying to convert to Python.  The engineer who wrote it originally says he doesn't remember how it works and I'm kind of stuck.

```
c=10;
s=5;
t=2*pi/s:2*pi/s:2*pi*c;
```

My little python brain doesn't understand how t can be a 1x50 array.  It looks like it should be length 3 vector or a 3 dimensional matrix.

Can anyone tell me how translate that t declaration into python??

Comment: t=start:step:end; generates a vector starting from start, in increment of step and ending at end. You can see why the matrix is 1x50. You can use linspace in MATLAB (and in Python) to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an Octave session:

```
>> c=10;
>> s=5;
>> t=2*pi/s:2*pi/s:2*pi*c;
>> 2*pi/s
ans =  1.2566
>> 2*pi*c
ans =  62.832
```

In `ipython`, the equivalent (ignoring the end point issue):

```
In [136]: c,s = 10,5
In [137]: 2*np.pi/s
Out[137]: 1.2566370614359172
In [138]: 2*np.pi*c
Out[138]: 62.83185307179586
In [139]: np.arange(2*np.pi/s, 2*np.pi*c, 2*np.pi/s).shape
Out[139]: (49,)
```

MATLAB uses start:step:stop

A closer pairing:

```
tt = linspace(2*pi/s, 2*pi*c, 50)
np.linspace(2*np.pi/s, 2*np.pi*c, 50)
```

Comment: I still don't completely understand it but np.linspace(2*np.pi/s, 2*np.pi*c, 50) matches my Matlab output to rounding error.  Thanks a lot!!